# How to read the time spent calculated by

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import time
start = time.time()
end = time.time()
print('Total time spent: {}'.format(str(timedelta(seconds=end-start))))
```

I varied the condition of my program and generated two times spent:

```
Total time spent: 0:00:00.063149
Total time spent: 0:00:00.153107
```

Is the first one 0.6 milliseconds and the 2nd one is 153 milliseconds? And the 2nd one is 2550 times slower than the first one (153/0.063)?

Answer (score 1):

the first is 63ms and the second is 153ms.  The second is 2.55 times slower than the first (153/63)

```
python3 -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
```

will give the time of

```
10000 loops, best of 5: 30.2 usec per loop
```

so you would know the efficacy of the code